# Какая будет ошибка при попытке удалить строку, на которую завязан внешний ключ?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Какая будет ошибка, при попытку удалить строку, на которую завязан внешний ключ (нарушение целостности)?

У самого БД нет, а онлайн сервисы или удаляют без проблем, или не поддерживают удаление.

Comment: Вообще, ошибка будет подобная: 
````The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_EmpEducation_Employees". The conflict occurred in database "AdventureWorks", table "dbo.EmpEducation", column 'empno'.
The statement has been terminated.````

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov вот, вполне подходит. выносите коммент как ответ, я приму.) Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Будет подобная ошибка:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_EmpEducation_Employees". The conflict occurred in database "AdventureWorks", table "dbo.EmpEducation", column 'empno'. The statement has been terminated.
```

Вообще, еще можно посмотреть результаты вот этого запроса:

```
 select * from sys.messages
```